# How to simplify too many if condition and capture the error out field in java

Tags: java, java-8, java-11

I have these fields `productID, productName, productDesc, productPrice` - all these are optional fields, so I'm checking if this key exists in the map if exist I'm assigning it to the variable and performing `null` check validation. Please find the code below - is there any better way of writing the below logic, how to avoid too many if in this code?

And I would like to capture the field which is failed to satisfy the null check.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

```
private void validate(Map<String, String> map) {
    String productID = null;
    String productName = null;
    String productDesc = null;
    String productPrice = null;

    if ((map.containsKey("PRODUCT_ID")))
        productID = map.get("PRODUCT_ID");

    if ((map.containsKey("PRODUCT_NAME")))
        productName = map.get("PRODUCT_NAME");

    if ((map.containsKey("PRODUCT_DESC")))
        productDesc = map.get("PRODUCT_DESC");

    if ((map.containsKey("PRODUCT_PRICE")))
        productPrice = map.get("PRODUCT_PRICE");

    if ((productID != null || productName != null) || (productDesc != null && productPrice != null)) {
        System.out.println("validation success");
    } else {
        System.out.println("validation failed"); // how to get the field name here which is failed to satisfy the above condition?
    }
}
```

Comment: I personally prefer to validate first and print invalid fields as you check them.  I.e. `if( !map.containsKey("PRODUCT_PRICE")){ System.out.println("PRODUCT_PRICE is invalid"); }`

Comment: `if(map.keySet().containsAll(List.of("PRODUCT_ID", "PRODUCT_NAME", "PRODUCT_DESC", "PRODUCT_PRICE"))) System.out.println("validation success"); else …`

Answer (score 2):

In your case the `containsKey` check is unnecessary. Because you initialize the variables with `null` and `Map.get(Key)` returns null if no value was found for the given key.

So just writing this does the same, but it's shorter.

```
String productID = map.get("PRODUCT_ID");
String productName = map.get("PRODUCT_NAME");
String productDesc = map.get("PRODUCT_DESC");
String productPrice = map.get("PRODUCT_PRICE");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one different approach that might be easy to extend:

```
private void validate2(Map<String, String> map) {
    String[] list = new String[]{"PRODUCT_ID", "PRODUCT_ID", "PRODUCT_DESC", "PRODUCT_PRICE"};
    String [] result = new String[list.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        String v = map.getOrDefault(list[i], null);
        if (v == null) {
            System.out.println("validation failed for " + list[i]);
        } else {
            result[i] = v;
        }
    }
    
    String productID = result[0];
    String productName = result[1];
    String productDesc = result[2];
    String productPrice = result[3];
}
```

Comment: There is no need for `getOrDefault(…, null)` as `get(…)` does already return `null` when the key is absent.

Comment: Ah ok, just took a look again at the api docs and you are correct @Holger

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
public void validateNonNullValues(Map<String, String> map, String... keys) {
    for (String key : keys) {
        if (map.get(key) == null) {
            System.out.println("validation failed for " + key);
        }
    }
}

validateNonNullValues(map, "PRODUCT_ID", "PRODUCT_ID", "PRODUCT_DESC", "PRODUCT_PRICE");
```